# Python faster import csv to dict

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, import

I want to import multiple csv files into a dictionary. Unfortunaetly my solution is very slow. How could I optimize that code?

Thank you in advance! :)

```
dats = os.listdir(path) #file_names
dat_names = [i.split(sep = "_")[0] for i in dats ] #should be key in dict
PFC_Dict = {}
i = 0
while i < len(dats):
    PFC_Dict[dat_names[i]] = pd.read_csv(str(path + str(dats[i])), sep =";", parse_dates= True, index_col=(0), names = ["Preis"], decimal =",", dayfirst  =True ).resample("15min").ffill()
    i =+ 1
```

Edit: Additional information:

- Number of import files: ~10 files.
- Size of files: ~ 1 MB, Shape of CSV: (160000,1)
- Context:

Result of the analysis should be a dataframe in following form:

- index presenting the file name
- columns representing different scenarions of the calculation (different parameters)

The files consist of a datetime index & corresponding prices. The files have different start dates and diffent prices, since these are forecasts.

I will  merge these dataframes on different data depending on the start dates of these. With seperate dataframes for each file I can find out there start date easily, since its index[0]. On the other hand If I would have one dataframe for all files, I thought its not that easy to find the start dates for each file.

Comment: Why have a dictionary of dataframes? Why not a single dataframe?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question, i.e. provide some context (how many files, how big are they, how long it currently takes on which h/w). Also, you're not just reading csv files, you're also resampling.

Comment: The best optimization trick probably hands down is to write your program to read csv in [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), and then create a binding for a Python package which you then publish. Then you can import this Python extension in your code as normal, and use it to read a csv file, no problem. There are a couple articles that walk you thru how to do exactly this, for example [this](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-rust-to-extend-python-360174ee5819) one.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Given that the speed critical parts of Pandas's CSV reader are written in C, this seems like an insane amount of work for very little benefit. The amount of effort required to pass complex datatypes like a dataframe into Python would be higher than writing the entire program in Rust.

Comment: @ddejohn: The reason for a dictionary is, that I want to have the file_name as information in the resulting dataframe. So I can use the key in the dictionary to define the name.  I could have have one column for each file and than referring to the column name which is probably a nice idea. But the files  have all a different date-range which I merge into one dataframe and afterwards I need to find out the start date. Merging shoudnt be a problem, but what would be an elegent way to find the index for the first value which is not nan?

Comment: @AlexS thank you! I added some information in the original post. To import one csv took just seconds. To imort a further one I stopped the script after ~10mins..

Comment: It really isn't clear at all why one data frame is seconds and one more is ... well, never ends. Do all of the dataframes *individually* load in seconds? Or does that second dataframe always take so long even if it is the only one?

Comment: @topsail Its really a thing with importing multiple files. Individually the import is fast, regardless if its the one or the other file. Just in having more than one file in the import folder, the script is running endless.

Comment: Hmmm. That is very strange. Apparently then you can just do one after another and it will all go quickly ... but, it doesn't, does it? Any more clues or context that might help? Could you separate simply reading the files from the other things going on to remove variables in this puzzle?

Comment: Oh dear, the reason was so easy! My code included:
 "i =+ 1" But the way to increment the variable ist i += 1. Therefore I was in an en endless loop as long more than one file should be imported --> len(import_list) < 1. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Nice one - we all missed it lol!

Answer (score 0):

Reading csv is a slow process because a csv is meant to be readable by humans. The most efficient file format is `.feather`. Luckily, Pandas has built-in support for feather files:

`.read_csv()` --> `.read_feather()`

`.to_csv()` --> `.to_feather()`

Run a script once that converts all the `.csv` files to `.feather`. To do this, loop through all the csv files and read them with `pd.read_csv()`. Next export it using `df.to_feather()`.

When you run your code now, it should read in the `.feather` files much faster. For me, I had a data file that took 30 seconds to read as a csv and 1 to 2 seconds to read as a feather file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem wasnt the speed of the code or the size of the data.. Just the code was wrong. I looped through the list of import files as long i < len(import_list) with following code:

```
i =+ 1
```

Obvisously it should be i += 1. Otherwise it looped endless through the list.

Thank you for all your replies!

Answer (score 0):

i personally like `pathlib` for working with file paths. you could do something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

# creates a posix path
folder_path = Path('/your/folder/')
# iterates through the directory and puts everything in a list
file_list = list(folder_path.iterdir())
PFC_Dict = {}
# iterate through the list and add items into the dict
for file in file_list:
    PFC_Dict[file.stem.split('_')[0]] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

this way you don't have to run a counter. maybe a solution for your future tasks